# How to import class from my maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import, dependencies

I have a maven dependency in my **pom.xml** file. I want to use the classes in the dependency. The dependency is a local thing. Somehow IDEA does not recognize and does not support import class or anything like that when I type the class name I want to use.

In MyLibrary i ran *mvn clean install* and I did that also after I added my dependency to the target project.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is it a Maven project?

Comment: Yes, it is a maven project.

Comment: Have you added your dependency to your local Maven repo?

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked that before.

Comment: `MyLibrary` is just a plain JAR, not Spring Boot?

Comment: It is not a jar. I just created my maven project, ran *mvn clean install* and I added this dependency. I checked if it is in the *.m2* and also ran *mvn clean install* in the project I want to use _MyLibrary_ in. Does it have to be a *.jar* ? I do not really work with maven so I do not a lot of things.

Comment: by saying "dependency is local thing" do you mean to say adding local jar as dependency?

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment it is not a jar. By saying it, I meant that it is not a library from public maven repository but it is just my maven project.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not a jar". How did you add it to your local repo?

Comment: The inner workings of Maven is still a mystery to me, especially when combined with IDEA. The problem might be that you need to register the dependancy first in `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries` due to IDEA handling Maven a bit differently.

Comment: You are right, mvn clean install probably generated a jar. I did not know how it works.

Comment: I tried adding it as a library now, but it did not help. I will try to restart the IDEA.

Comment: Adding as a library did not help.

Comment: There could be a problem with the dependancy, or IDEA's indexing where the dependancy is there and loaded correctly but it's not recognized when typing code. You could try building the project, see if IDEA corrects itself or throws an error.

Comment: No it did not. It is just not working.

Comment: *Answering my own question:*
I was not careful and when I was creating MyLibrary project I did not put my class in a package. It was in a default package and that was the issue. (I created it only for the purposes of trying dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

If you type the class name (jackson) in your code and hit ctrl + space, Eclipse will suggest matches and automatically import the one you select.

Ex:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.*;
```